# Pass NSURL from One Class To Another

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my appDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I have the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.thejenkinsinstitute.com/Journal/"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString * aString = content;
NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<p>To Download the PDF, " intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before #
while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *substring = nil;
    [scanner scanString:@"<p>To Download the PDF, <a href=\"" intoString:nil]; // Scan the # character
    if([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&substring]) {
        // If the space immediately followed the #, this will be skipped
        [substrings addObject:substring];
    }
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"" intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before next #
}
// do something with substrings

NSString *URLstring = [substrings objectAtIndex:0];
self.theheurl = [NSURL URLWithString:URLstring];
NSLog(@"%@", theheurl);
[substrings release];
```

The console printout for theheurl gives me a valid URL ending in .pdf.

In the class I would like to load the URL, I have the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
_appdelegate.theheurl = currentURL;
NSLog(@"%@", currentURL);
NSLog(@"%@", _appdelegate.theheurl);
[worship loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:currentURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

However, both NSLogs in that class come back null.  What am I Doing wrong in getting the NSURL from the AppDelegate to the class to load it?

Comment: this line makes problem `_appdelegate.theheurl = currentURL;` you are replacing the appdelegate url with a null string

Comment: Check My edited Answer and let me Know if you have further query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Second Code Just Change the Assigning values.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

AppDelegate *appdell= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  currentURL=appdell.theheurl;
NSLog(@"%@", currentURL);
NSLog(@"%@", appdell.theheurl);
[worship loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:currentURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

Comment: It is still coming back as null in the console

Comment: Check my Edited Answer it works for me hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from your above lines that you need to get the url from some class, say `MyFirstViewControlle`, and; after that you try to save that url in your `appDelegate`, say `MyAppDelegate`, so you can use the same in different controller say, `MyOtherViewController`... if I'm in right direction, then please clarify me how you make the `object of appDelegate`, it should be like this:(in your `MyFirstViewController`)

```
MyAppDelegate *objMyAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and, be also sure that you synthesize of url property in your appDelegate, like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSURL *theURL;
@property(strong)NSURL *theURL;//ios 5.0
```

After that, as you've already made delegate object, do this:

```
objMyAppDelegate.theURL = _currentURL;
```

Tell me if you further have any query.